# How to Remove OpenSSL v1 on Windows 11 PC

Tags: openssl, windows-11

I have an OpenSSL v1 instance installed on my Windows 11 PC. I don't know which application installed it to start with. Still, I want to remove that version of OpenSSL while keeping other instances (v3.0.9+) alone. Any guidance would be appreciated.

I am not familiar with OpenSSL at all, thus, I am not comfortable by just deleting associated DLLs without guidance.